# Call Objective C custom init function from Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, inheritance

Class A is writen in Objective C and have a custom init fucntion

```
@interface A ()

....

@end

@implementation A

- (id)customInitImplementedInA
{
    ... 
    return self;
}
```

Class B inherits from Class A and uses this custom init in the following way:

```
@interface B : A ()

....

@end

@implementation B
+(instancetype)instanceB{
    B *b = [[B alloc] customInitImplementedInA];
    ...
    return b;
}
```

Now I would like to create class C writen in **Swift** that inharits from A and uses the same init function. How do I do that?

```
class C: A {
  //How do I use customInitImplementedInA here?
}
```

Comment: In your actual `customInitImplementedInA`, the method name starts with `init`?

Comment: @OOPer Yes it is

Comment: Then no problem.

Comment: @OOPer So what is the answer?

Comment: You have already two.

Comment: @OOPer I commented on them. They're not working

Comment: You need to show your actual name of the initializer, or else you need to interpret method call in the answers as initializer call.

Comment: @OOPer The name is initWithDefaultNib

Comment: It takes one parameter? Why don't you write the actual name in your question? Using pseudo name makes it complex.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this via `super.methodname` syntax.

```
class C: A {
    init() {
        super.customInitImplementedInA()
        // Any extra initialization for C goes here.
    }
}
```

Comment: got an error for override: Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass. Removed it and got an error for customInitImplementedInA: Value of type 'A' has no member 'customInitImplementedInA'

Comment: My mistake.  If class A does not have a base init, then you would not need the override.  Is customInitImplementedInA exposed via the interface or is it private?  If it's private, you will not be able to access it.

Comment: It is indeed exposed via the interface. Can't imagine why this error arises

Comment: Does customInit have parameters and are you calling the initializer with proper swift syntax? When you do the super. does autocomplete provide anything relating to the methods from class A?

Answer (score 0):

If you inherit your swift class from Obj-C than your swift clas will have obj-c init().
if you need to call it you can include it to your swift init.

```
 class C: A {

        var message: B?

        init(message: B) {
            super.customInitImplementedInA()

            self.message = message

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the var message: B?

Comment: its just example of your custom init. there can be any var from your C class.